# How to get the file link from a SharePoint/OneDrive Sync location

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, registrykey

I am currently using Registry Editor to obtain the cloud OneDrive URL of a local OneDrive folder, through:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\` -> `UrlNameSpace`.

However, for shared folders I cannot seem to obtain the correct path based on the `UrlNameSpace` property. For example the following below returns:

- **C: Drive path (MountPoint)** - `C:\Users\nathan.hurley\MyCompany\John Smith - ShareFolder`
- **(UrlNameSpace)** - `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith_mycompany_com/Documents`

Following the example above, if I'm trying to get the cloud OneDrive URL for:

`C:\Users\nathan.hurley\MyCompany\John Smith - ShareFolder\Test`

Replacing the C: Drive path with the UrlNameSpace will produce the following path:

`https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith_mycompany_com/Documents/Test`.

The problem with this online link, is that it doesn't obtain the root synced folder and opening the link will lead to a 404 page error. The correct URL should be the following:

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/personal/john_smith_mycompany_com/Documents/ShareFolder/Test

Again, I've noticed this issue only occurs with shared folders and within the Registry Editor, these folders also include an additional property called `IsFolderScope`. Is there an efficient way to determine which folders are Shared Folders other than checking the `IsFolderScope` property? Also, are shared folders the only folders that include this property?

[image]

Reference: https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/12/get-url-from-sync.html